# Angular model for input

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-checked="false" name="one"><br/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="master" name="two">
```

It works. But if i replace "checkbox" to "radio" it doesn't work. I tired to try make one radio disabled when other checked.

Why it doesn't work? How to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Radio button use `ng-value` instead... Radio button work based on `value` to mark a value as selected. You need either `[value="" | ng-value=""]`

```
<input type="radio"
       ng-model=""
       [value="" |
       ng-value=""]>
```

Like:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="boolean" ng-model="myValue" /> True
 <input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="boolean"  ng-model="myValue" /> False
```

Here is a [**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jy3nN/)

Or with strings values like:

```
$scope.myValue = 'Car'
```

**html**

```
 <input type="radio" ng-value="'Car'" name="string1" ng-model="myValue" /> Car
 <input type="radio" ng-value="'Airplane'" name="string1"  ng-model="myValue" /> Airplane
```

Here is the [**second Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQuQ5/)

Comment: the question was: How to make one radio disabled when other checked. And notice - that radios were in separate groups. But I'll try. Sorry, i'm a very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works fine.

**HTML**

```
<input class="radio2" type="radio" id="r1" name="group1"
       ng-model="radioValue"
       ng-value="1">
<input class="radio2" type="radio" id="r2" name="group1"
       ng-model="radioValue"
       ng-value="2">
```

**Inside Your Controller**

```
$scope.radioValue = -1; /* Select none. */
$scope.radioValue = 0; /* Select none. */
$scope.radioValue = 3; /* Select none. */
$scope.radioValue = 1; /* Select r1. */
$scope.radioValue = 2; /* Select r2. */

var selected = $scope.radioValue; /* get selected value. */
```

Comment: if i add ng-checked="false" to the input, $scope.radioValue is 2.

Comment: In r1 input you added this?